# CORS error using localhost but not using domain

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm developing a react web app which communicates with a DRF backend via axios. While developing locally, I handled CORS by installing django-cors-headers and adding localhost:3000 to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST (3000 is the default port for react w/ create-react-app):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
)
```

This worked fine until I deployed to a remote server, when I suddenly started seeing CORS errors again:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/path/' from 
origin 'http://example.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy...
```

which was baffling to me, since it already worked when I was developing locally.

This had me stumped for hours until sheer frustration led me to change the react request from

```
axios.post(localhost:8000/api/path/, {                                          
    key1: val1,                                      
    key2: val2,                                          
    ...                                        
})
.then(response => {
    doSomeStuff(response);
});
```

to

```
axios.post(example.com:8000/api/path/, {                                          
    key1: val1,                                      
    key2: val2,                                          
    ...                                        
})
.then(response => {
    doSomeStuff(response);
});
```

and the whitelist from

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
)
```

to

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'example.com:3000',
)
```

At which point the CORS errors stopped.

My question is: why did this happen? My understanding was that localhost and example.com were two names for the same server, but every other combination of whitelisting localhost/example.com and requesting localhost/example.com results in an error. What is the difference from a CORS perspective?

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` and `example.com` are **not** two names for the same server. `localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1`, a local address, ie the server is inside your computer. `example.com` resolves to a remote server.

CORS-allowing localhost allows requests from localhost. CORS-allowing example.com allows requests from example.com. This is not a bug.

Comment: Aren't the two the same from the perspective of example.com?

Comment: No. At the `example.com` server, a request to `localhost` and `example.com` will both land *on the same computer*, but not *on the same socket*: the [layer 5](https://microchip.wdfiles.com/local--files/tcpip:tcp-ip-five-layer-model/layer_terminology.JPG) address is different, so they may refer to different programs - in any case, they must be differentiated in the CORS headers.